# How to load next URL with engine.load()

Tags: java, javafx

everyone. I have a problem in using javaFX. I need to load URL (auth-form), enter auth data, then another URL must load, i tried to do this with javaFX:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
final WebView view = new WebView();

    final WebEngine engine = view.getEngine();
    engine.load(VK_AUTH_URL);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(view));
    primaryStage.show();

    engine.locationProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>(){
@Override
public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
        //if token is exist, then reading token and uid
        if(newValue.contains("access_token=")){
        tokenUrl="";
        userId="";
        //reading token...
        int beg = newValue.indexOf("access_token=");
        int end = newValue.indexOf("&expires");
        for(int i=beg+13 ;i<end; i++){
    tokenUrl+=newValue.charAt(i);
    vkConn.setToken(tokenUrl);
            }
            //...and uid
            beg = newValue.indexOf("user_id=");
            end = newValue.length();
            for(int i=beg+8 ;i<end; i++){
                userId+=newValue.charAt(i);
    }
            vkConn.setUserId(userId);
            primaryStage.close();   
        }
}

});
if(VKconn.isReady()){  
   engine.load(VK_FRIENDS_URL);
   primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(view));
   primaryStage.show();

   //primaryStage.close();    
   }

}
```

}

But when auth data is entered, form just closes and nothing happened. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? If so, can you edit the question and add them?

Comment: You probably need to look up how to store cookies.

Comment: How is the data getting entered?  Are you just typing it in, then pressing the form’s submit button?  And if you don’t want the window to close, why are you calling `primaryStage.close()`?